# ansbile stdout_line to new strings

Tags: bash, ansible, ansible-2.x

I try to get bash tool for db output to ansbisle string,s but doesn't found no any working solution

```
   - set_fact:
        db_data: "{{ db.stdout_lines  }}"
   - debug: var=db_data
```

Here is debug output

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "db_data": [
        "host: localhost",
        "username: user",
        "password: pass",
        "database: db_name"
    ]
}
```

How possible get host, username, password, database as unique strings?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Get host, username, password, database as unique strings."*

A: Instead of a list, create a dictionary. Then simply reference the attributes. For example

```
   - set_fact:
        db_data: "{{ db_data|default({})|combine(item|from_yaml) }}"
      loop: "{{ db.stdout_lines }}"
    - debug:
        var: db_data
    - debug:
        var: db_data.username
```

give

```
    "db_data": {
        "database": "db_name", 
        "host": "localhost", 
        "password": "pass", 
        "username": "user"
    }

    "db_data.username": "user"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- debug:
       msg: "{{ item.split(':')[1] }}"
  with_items: " {{ db_data }} "
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.